# How to design and query graph relationships in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am having difficulties trying to design a graph-like relationship in Postgres. For example:

```
create table action (
    user integer references user(id),
    relation varchar(255),
    target integer references user(id),
    created_at timestamp not null default now()
);

insert into action(1, "follow", 2)
insert into action(2, "liked", 4)
insert into action(3, "follow", 2)
```

Is that the best way to define domain-specific relationships between entities? How about querying that in an efficient way? Common questions I have are: Show me users that users that I follow liked.

I am aware of a few extensions, such as Apache AGE, but without any extensions, what would be the best practice for a scenario like this?

Comment: Why not use the extension? The whole point about them is that they are extremely flexible - allowing you to use the whole power of PostgreSQL and write your own "special" queries **also**! Thnk TimescaleDB...

Comment: I don't have access to compile & install an extension like Age. I'm using a cloud solution for Postgres.

Comment: @Iebaga - change vendor? :-) Seriously - after having tested locally, tell them that you'll move if they don't allow it! If they want you as a client, they'll give your request serious consideration... [This](https://help.heroku.com/7KM0BSLY/how-do-i-add-a-postgres-extension-to-my-database) sort of crap is not acceptable - or run a bare-metal server?

Comment: Why cant you join followed users with liking users?